# Automatically Clicking an element in another Component from a different Component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a react app which on clicking an element in the sidebar component it automatically affects another element in the react app. But I have no idea on how to achieve this.
Below ComponentOne is the body and ComponentTwo is the sidebar.

The App.js file Containing all components:

```
import ComponentOne from "./ComponentOne"
import ComponentTwo from "./ComponentTwo"

export default function App(){
return(
<ComponentOne />
<ComponentTwo />
)
}
```

In my ComponentOne:

```
export default ComponentOne(){
const [inputedText, setInputText]=useState('')

const handleChange =(event)=> {
    const newValue = event.target.value;
    setInputText(newValue);
  }

const saveText=()=>{
alert("Your text have been saved")
}

return(
<>
<input type={text} value={inputedText} onChange={handleChange} />
<button onClick={saveText}>Save text</button>
</>
)
}
```

In ComponentTwo which will be a sidebar:
On clicking the list item "Save Text" it should automatically click the button in ComponentOne.

```
export default ComponentTwo(){
return(
<>
<nav>
<ul>
<li>Save Text</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</>
)
}
```

Comment: From the question it seems your side bar is acting like a button and once sidebar button is clicked it should update the text in component 1 is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

you should follow steps below:

1- create state in parent component

```
import ComponentOne from "./ComponentOne"
import ComponentTwo from "./ComponentTwo"

export default function App(){
const [inputedText, setInputText]=useState('')

return(
<ComponentOne setInputText={setInputText} inputedText={inputedText} />
<ComponentTwo inputedText={inputedText} />
)
}
```

2- pass setState to ComponentOne

3- change state when click

4- use state in ComponentTwo

```
export default ComponentTwo({inputedText}){
return(
<>
<nav>
<ul>
<li>{inputedText}</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</>
)
```

}

Comment: I was working on similar to the question I just asked, all I need to know is how to automatically click on a button from another component but you answer does not help. I am really grateful you tried answering it though. Thank you.

Comment: you don't need to click on button, you just change the state you want (use global state management's)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like declare your state in parent component and pass props to each component seperately

App.tsx

```
import ComponentOne from "./ComponentOne";
import ComponentTwo from "./ComponentTwo";

function App() {
  const [inputedText, setInputText]=useState("Test");
  const saveText = () => {
    setInputText("Text Saved")
  }
  return (
    <>
      <ComponentOne inputedText={inputedText}/> 
      <ComponentTwo saveText={saveText}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ComponentOne.tsx

```
const ComponentOne = (props:any) => {

  return (
    <>
        <input type="text" value={props.inputedText} />
    </>
  );
};

export default ComponentOne;
```

ComponentTwo.tsx

```
const ComponentTwo = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <>
      <li>
        <button onClick={props.saveText}>Save Text</button>
      </li>
    </>
  );
};

export default ComponentTwo;
```